# Restore windows' positions and sizes on startup in Dreamweaver

Tags: dreamweaver

It's rather annoying to setup windows' sizes and position every time after startup.

Is it possible to set not just reopening files on startup but also restoring their windows' positions and sizes?

Updated with a screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to do `right click` on Dreamweaver Icon on your desktop, or menu list. And you will see the option to set it's default as Maximize for example.

*Sorry, still on Ubuntu so that can't get more precision answer*

Comment: I meant inner windows. I've updated question with screenshot